# wish to be vs. wish I was

Tags: wish

what is the difference between "*I wish to be a pilot*" and "*I wish I was a pilot*"? 
To me it sounds like "I wish to be" refers to the future while "I wish I was" refers to an imaginary status in the present 
Thanks

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

- "**I wish to be a pilot**" refers to the future. You have a wish to become a pilot. Most probably you are already doing something to become a pilot; moving in that direction so as to become a pilot.
- "**I wish I was a pilot**" refers to the present. It's called **the subjunctive mood**. You use it when you're talking about something that isn't true or when you want to express a wish. The past simple indicative of "**be**" is correct, even the Oxford Learner’s Dictionary considers it as correct, however, "**I wish I were**" is the most correct form, and, if you are writing a formal piece of writing, definitely go for it.